# How do I validate a checkbox array in laravel?

Tags: html, arrays, laravel

I've been trying to validate all 10 checkbox array items but I cannot seem to find or understand how to use Laravels validator to validate a checkbox array.
The below code is my array HTML.

```
<div id="CLAagree" style="display: none;">
    <div class="form-group form-check">
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <div class="checkbox checkbox-green ck-button">
                <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" oninput="this.className = ''" name="claAgree[]" id="CLAagreeCB1" onclick="saveOnboard()" >
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have tried to get all info that I can about this but I just can't seem to understand arrays in validation for some reason.
I know adding "required" made the inputs required but I have 10 so at least one will be required but I need 10 to be required. Does anyone have any options? I'm just lost at this point lol

```
$rules = array(
    "claAgree" => "required", 
    "claAgree.*" => "required",
);
$validation = Validator::make($request->all(),$rules);
if($validation->fails()) return back()->with('error',$validation->messages()->first());
```

[Here is a link to show how the array is posted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VTlc.jpg)

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#conditionally-adding-rules  , you can check here define how to validate array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > You can do like  that ,check you request array name (claAgree.*.claAgree) , 
> >         then define  the input value , if same then you can use same like that

```
 $rules = array(
        "claAgree" => "required", 
        "claAgree.*.claAgree" => "required",
    );

    $validation = Validator::make($request->all(),$rules);
    if($validation->fails()) return back()->with('error',$validation->messages()->first());
```

Comment: When I try that I get this error.
"The claAgree.0.claAgree field is required."